# How do I sort ggplot bars based on values calculated in a proportional stacked bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a proportional stacked bar graph that shows percentages in various groups. I would like to sort the bars (left to right) based on the percentage "Yes" in each group.  That is, I want the bar with the most "Yes" values to be first, followed by the next most "Yes" category, etc.   Can I do this inside of a `ggplot()` or do I need to preprocess/calculate the percentages and sort the factor levels (e.g., `forcats::fct_reorder()` or `forcats::fct_infreq()`) before the plot?

Below is some sample data and my code. Here I would like the code to draw the cow bar (on the left) then the dog bar (in the middle) then the cat bar (on the right).  In the real data there are many levels.

```
demo <- data.frame(
  thingy = rep(c("cow", "dog", "cat"), c(10, 10, 10)), 
  value = factor(c(rep("Yes", 9), "No",
                   rep("Yes", 7), rep("No", 3),
                   rep("Yes", 0), rep("No", 10)),
                 levels = c("Yes", "No")))

library(ggplot2)
demo |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = thingy, fill = value)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("darkred", "darkgray")
  ) + 
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = scales::label_percent()
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

To sort the bars based on the percentage of "Yes" values in each group, you can calculate the percentage of "Yes" values for each level of the "thingy" variable and then sort the levels based on the percentage. You can do this using the dplyr and forcats packages. Here's an example code that should work for your data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)

demo_sorted <- demo %>%
  group_by(thingy) %>%
  summarize(yes_perc = mean(value == "Yes")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(desc(yes_perc)) %>%
  mutate(thingy = fct_reorder(thingy, yes_perc)) %>%
  left_join(demo, by = "thingy")

ggplot(demo_sorted, aes(x = thingy, fill = value)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkred", "darkgray")) + 
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_percent())
```

This code first groups the data by the "thingy" variable, calculates the percentage of "Yes" values for each group, sorts the groups in descending order of percentage, and then uses the fct_reorder() function to reorder the levels of the "thingy" variable based on the percentage. The sorted data is then used to create the plot using ggplot() as before.

Note that we use arrange(desc(yes_perc)) to sort the percentages in descending order so that the bars are ordered from left to right with the highest percentage of "Yes" values on the left. You can change desc(yes_perc) to yes_perc to sort the percentages in ascending order if you prefer the opposite order of bars.

The code without data being processed:

```
ggplot(demo, aes(x = thingy, fill = value)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkred", "darkgray")) + 
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = scales::label_percent(),
    expand = c(0, 0),
    limits = c(0, 1)
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = after_stat(paste0(sprintf("%.1f", stat(count / sum(count) * 100)), "%"))),
    stat = "count",
    position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5),
    size = 3
  )
```

Comment: Thanks @GaB! Is there a way to get at the percentages that the `ggplot()` is calculating if the data are not preprocessed?  I am thinking there is a way to get at them with `after_stat()` but I don't see how.

Comment: @itsMeInMiami - I have added the code without data being processed separately, but I believe it is better to separate the pre-processing the data first and then ggplot it. It s up to you. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: The revised code does a nice job plotting the overall percentages but the bars are not ordered based on the percentage "yes" which is key for the real data (which is showing the most likely side effect of a surgery followed by the 2nd most likely etc).  Ideally text annotation from the geom_text would be paying attention to the grouping.  So, the red cow bar would be 90%, the red dog bar would be labeled 70%.  I see how to do it using the pre-processed data.  I am just curious to know if there is a sane way to do it in the plot object.

Comment: got it, let me see

Comment: The left join is going to keep the original version of thingy.  So call it something like thingy_ordered in your mutate and then plot thingy_ordered.

Comment: @itsMeInMiami - you've solved it, right?

Comment: I am hoping someone will offer a solution that does not require preprocessing.  If nobody comes up with a solution I will close this off.  Thank you kindly for the help!